# Create a program that counts number of odd, even and zero numbers C++

Tags: c++

```css
#include <iostream>using namespace std;
const int LIMIT=10;
int main () {
  float counter;
  int number=0;
  int zeros=0;
  int odds=0;
  int evens=0;
  cout << "Please enter " << LIMIT << " integers, " << "positive, negative, or zeros." << endl;
  cout << "The numbers you entered are:" << endl;
  for (counter=1;      counter <=LIMIT;      counter++) {
    cin>>number;
    switch (number / 2) {
      case 0: evens++;
      if (number=0) zeros++;
      case 1: case -1: odds++;
    }
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "There are " << evens << " evens, " << "which includes " << zeros << " zeros." << endl;
  cout << "The number of odd numbers is: " << odds << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Hi All,

I have a varsity question which has had me stumped all day. I need to amend the above script to allow me to enter 10 variable integers and the program must return me the total number of even numbers, total number of odd numbers and total number of zeros.

I have tried multiple solutions including (number % 2 == 0) in order to make my cases work under my switch parameter however I am missing something.

Please can someone assist pushing me into the right path.

(I know i need to remove the negative case but I wanted to post the raw code incase I take something out or ammend something that is needed)

Comment: always initialize your variables:  `int evens` doesn't say a thing about its value; it can be -68, 35241 as well as 0.

Comment: great stuff - edited the question :)

Comment: Got it working, cannot believe i wanted to pull my hair out for that :)

Comment: You are missing a break in the switch statement

Comment: Given an array of 3 elements (even, odd, zero) initialized to zero and a number n : tally [n ? n&1 : 2]++

Answer (score 0):

```css
#include <iostream>using namespace std;
const int LIMIT=10;
int main () {
  float counter;
  int number=0;
  int zeros=0;
  int odds=0;
  int evens=0;
  int n=0;
  cout << "Please enter " << LIMIT << " integers, " << "positive, negative, or zeros." << endl;
  cout << "The numbers you entered are:" << endl;
  for (counter=1;
  counter <=LIMIT;
  counter++) {
    cin>>number;
    n=(number%2);
    switch (n) {
      case 0: evens++;
      if (number==0) zeros++;
      break;
      case 1: odds++;
    }
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "There are " << evens << " evens, " << "which includes " << zeros << " zeros." << endl;
  cout << "The number of odd numbers is: " << odds << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks to papagaga managed to get it working - i think i was far too tired :)

Comment: Accept your own answer so the question closes.  Also `counter` is a `float` but it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I see that. I can only accept in 2 days time

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> myvec = {0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 5, 4, 9};
std::vector<int> zeros;
std::vector<int> evens;
std::vector<int> odds;

for (auto i : myvec) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        if (i == 0) zeros.push_back(i);
        else evens.push_back(i);
    }

    else
        odds.push_back(i);
}

std::cout << zeros.size();
std::cout << evens.size();
std::cout << odds.size();

return 0;
}
```

If you don't want zeros to be in the evens vector, this will work.

Comment: Thanks Stan - much appreciated! will keep this for future reference as well